# How to inverse subset in R?

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to make non-overlapping subsets of a totally inclusive group in R. The first subset contains pairs of elements from the totally inclusive group. The other subset should be all of the elements in the totally inclusive group, but not in the first subset.

```
poplength <- 10
samples <- 7
numpair <- 2
totallyinclusivegroup <- sample(1:poplength, samples)
Subset1 <- sample(totallyinclusivegroup, size = numpair*2)
```

I don't know how to get a "Subset2" that includes everything in "totallyinclusivegroup" but not in Subset 1. I've tried using the "-" operator, with no success. For example,

```
Subset2  <- totallyinclusivegroup[-Subset1]
```

does not work, and includes elements from Subset1. Any advice/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can negate with `!` on the logical vector from `%in%` so that TRUE -> FALSE and viceversa

```
 out <- totallyinclusivegroup[!totallyinclusivegroup %in% Subset1]
```

-output

```
Subset1
#[1] 2 6 9 7

totallyinclusivegroup
#[1] 3 2 6 1 9 7 8

 out
#[1] 3 1 8
```

---

Or an easier option is `setdiff`

```
setdiff(totallyinclusivegroup, Subset1)
#[1] 3 1 8
```

If there are duplicate elements, it is better to use `vsetdiff` from `vecsets`

```
library(vecsets)
vsetdiff(totallyinclusivegroup, Subset1)
```

Comment: setdiff worked for me, from the dplyr pkg

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#Code
Subset2  <- totallyinclusivegroup[-which(totallyinclusivegroup%in% Subset1 )]
```

Output:

```
totallyinclusivegroup
[1]  8  5 10  2  9  1  3
Subset1
[1]  5 10  3  9
Subset2
[1] 8 2 1
```